# Pull certain information from another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, filter, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tnAtFgxCl2DnyYL0cjzijsqw8WlvC1BxI80hduaPwi0/edit?usp=sharing

=filter(Sheet1!2:39, Loads!D2:D="Elijah Fisher",Loads!Z2:Z=13)

Working on making statement sheets using formulas.
First sheet contains all the information 2nd sheet is the workers statement.
Only want information from cells A, E, F, J, K, O to be pulled that go with the week number.
tried formula =filter(Sheet1!2:39, Loads!D2:D="Elijah Fisher",Loads!Z2:Z=13) but the whole rows of information is being pulled.

Answer (score 1):

You can use QUERY() formula to fetch filtered data from another sheet.

Please see formula below:

```
=query(Sheet1!A:O, "Select A, E, F, J, K, O where D='Elijah Fisher'", 0)
```

This formula resulted to this:

[image]

Comment: It's more flexible when you pull out name from the sheet and not write it literally in the formula: =query(Sheet1!A:O, "Select A, E, F, J, K, O where D='"&B1&"'", 0) will do the job (you use "&cell reference&") to insert it into query content.

Comment: @Jason E. What is Sheet 1 has a =IMPORTRANGE formula that has the link to another spreadsheet on A1

Comment: @NCY as far as I know, it should still get the value on A1 which is the value from the IMPORTRANGE sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to change the headers on the individual statement sheet to be exactly the same as the headers used in `Sheet1` of your example, such as below:

[image: New Headers]

Secondly, in cell `A6` on the `Elijah Fisher` sheet, enter the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$39),TRANSPOSE((Sheet1!$D$1:$D$39=$B$1)*(Sheet1!$Z$1:$Z$39=$E$1)))),,MATCH(A$5,Sheet1!$A$1:$Z$1,0)),"")
```

Drag this across to cell `F6`.

Below is an example for **Elijah Fisher** from **Week 13**:

[image: Example - EF]

Below is another example for **Justin Wright** from **Week 13**:

[image: Example - JW]

Comment: What is Sheet 1 has a =IMPORTRANGE formula that has the link to another spreadsheet  on A1